# How can I get current time from PLC (Beckhoff)

Tags: plc, st

I am trying to get the current time from the PLC (Beckhoff-cx5130). I have tried "GETSYSTEMTIME", but I am not getting any output.
I also tried "NT_GetTime" "TIMESTRUCT" and "T_FILETIME" but showing some compiling error (Could be a library issue).
Any suggestion (Example code) regarding this issue will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: You could also try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to add the TcUtilities.Lib. After adding it, everything worked. For more info [see Beckhoff's InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcplclib_tc2_utilities/35137547.html&id=)

### Example code

```
PROGRAM MAIN
VAR
    fbSystemTime : GETSYSTEMTIME;
    timeAsFileTime : T_FILETIME;
    timeAsDT : DT;
END_VAR

fbSystemTime(
    timeLoDW=>timeAsFileTime.dwLowDateTime,
    timeHiDW=>timeAsFileTime.dwHighDateTime 
);

timeAsDT := FILETIME_TO_DT(timeAsFileTime);
```